# In logical progression, what things does a person need to know to design a robust opamp from BJTs

Tags: operational-amplifier, bjt, physical-design

Opamps contain things like current mirrors, differential stage, push-pull pair and much more. Once a person starts from learning that BJT has 3 terminals for which Ic≈Ie≈βIb, what topics must a person master until they are able to design their own OpAmp. A target would be to atleast design a the "741" opamp. As we go into depth there are more complex devices that have ultra low noise or work with only a +ve rail voltage e.t.c. Lets ignore that for now.

So what topics must a person master, in logical order, to be able to understand the design of and design their own 741 opamp?

Comment: As a purely intellectual exercise perhaps designing your own op amp might keep you off the streets for a while but seriously (1) its already been done and published over the net (see http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee140/sp12/labs/Lab2.ee140.s11.v1.pdf for example) and (2) a '741' type op amp is hardly cutting edge technology and for the price of the bjts I could buy a really good op amp without wasting valuable drinking time.

Comment: The most simple "opamp" can constructed with 3 transistors. Relatively high input resistance, low output resistance, simple feedback amplification, with quite high open-loop gain and a "good" frequency response  http://www.edn.com/design/components-and-packaging/4368741/Build-an-op-amp-with-three-discrete-transistors

Comment: I am curious how its done, I "want to know how its done".

Comment: Do you want to build OPAMP on IC level or OPAMP from more components connected together (ex. AXIAL-0.2 resistors and so on)? OPAMPs built from more components connected together are hard to build because the gain of the transistors are variable, while in the IC level the gains are almost the same (because they are made out of same silicon wafer)

Comment: If the gain is to be matched, one can always get an IC with matched NPNs for using in differential stage. Besides, as far as I understand, the purpose is to design such that the dependance on beta is minimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions like this can be difficult to answer because a lot of design is understanding why *not* to do it "the other way".  You can't see this by looking at the 741 circuit because these other topologies simply aren't there.

But a reasonable answer would be to look at how textbooks approach this.  Clearly writers of these books have to determine at least some base level of knowledge that must be taught before they can approach the 741 in detail.

Look at the fairly standard [Microelectronic Circuits](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/microelectronic-circuits-9780195323030?cc=us&lang=en&#) textbook by Sedra/Smith.  Section 12.3 is "The 741 Op-Amp Circuit".  So presumably, you would have to know at most everything up to this point in the book from the time they describe the BJT.  This should provide an upper limit for understanding the 741.

But I would like to remark that it is a long road from understanding how a circuit works to understanding why it was designed that way then further to being able to design it yourself.  It is a worthy trip to make, just not a short one.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent question. Please enjoy this exellent PDF book, provided free by the author (who designed the much loved 555 timer). It will cover everything you need to know, starts from the beginning, and assumes no prior knowledge.

http://www.designinganalogchips.com/

First half builds up to op-amp design, second half uses them, and introduces more analog electronics concepts.

Edit: spelling